# Basic principles: independent choice, counting functions and subsets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Calculate the number of passwords of length 8 using letters A..Z such that adjacent letters are distinct. For example, GJLYNDBF is a good password, while GJLYYDBF is not good (two adjacent Y's).

Comment: The leftmost letter can be anything. After that $\dots$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Choose your letters from left to right. There are $26$ possible choices for the first letter. How many for the second? What about the third? The fourth? ...